# Optimization: Are Second Derivatives more "Useful" than "First Derivatives"?

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, gradient-descent

As a quick summary:

- **Gradient Descent** based algorithms try to find the minimum of the function they are optimizing by repeatedly using information obtained from the First Derivatives
- **Quasi Newton Methods** (e.g. BFGS) tries to find the minimum of the function by repeatedly using/approximating information obtained from the Second Derivatives

Thus, it is almost a logical conclusion to believe that for the exact same (convex) function, Gradient Descent would on average require fewer calculations per iteration when compared to Quasi Newton Methods.

**But in the spirit of "tradeoffs" - are there any theoretical results that show Quasi-Newton Methods gain stronger convergence rates compared to Gradient Descent based algorithms ?**

For instance, since information about the second derivative gives the optimization algorithm additional knowledge about the function's local curvature - in theory, we would expect this additional knowledge would "better lead" the optimization algorithm to the minimum when compared to information only about the first derivative (especially in higher dimensional functions). **Or is this additional second derivative information gained by Quasi-Newton Methods generally negligible compared to the first derivative information, and as a result, there is no general "strength in convergence" obtained by Quasi-Newton Methods when compared to Gradient Descent?**

Thus: **Are there any theoretical results that compare the "strength of convergence" for Quasi-Newton Methods vs. Gradient Descent Based Algorithms?**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Methods more efficient than , say , Newton's method usually use the first AND the second derivate. For finding turning points , the first derivate is utterly irrelevant. The usefulness of the derivates depends on what you actually want to determine.